# How to code this iterative process?

Tags: equation-solving, iteration

I am facing difficulty to realize this double iterative process.

The equations in question are

[image]

The flow chart for the iterative process is given as

[image]

The different parameters are defined as

```
alphan=1.72*10^(-4);
alphap=2.037*10^(-4);
L=1.3*10^(-3);
A=2.08*10^(-6);
kp=1.265;
kn=1.011;
sigmap=1.314e-5;
sigman=1.119e-5;
alphapn=alphap-alphan;
Rpn=L/(A)*(sigmap+sigman);
RL=1;
Kpn=(A/L)*(kp+kn);
cf=4205;
cc=4153;
hf=80;
hc=1000;
Tfin=773;
Tcin=353;
mf=20;
mc=20;
```

The equations are

```
qh[i, j] = cf*mf*(Tf[i, j] - Tf[i + 1, j])/ny

qh[i, j] = hf*Sf[i, j]*(Tfav[i, j] - Th[i + 1, j])

qh[i, j] = alphapn*I1*Th[i, j] + Kpn*(Th[i, j] - TL[i, j]) - 0.5*I1^2*Rpn

qL[i, j] = cc*mc*(Tc[i + 1, j] - Tc[i + 1, j])/ny

qL[i, j] = hc*Sc[i, j]*(TL[i, j] - Tcav[i, j])

qL[i, j] = alphapn*I1*TL[i, j] + Kpn*(Th[i, j] - TL[i, j]) + 0.5*I1^2*Rpn

I1 = Sum[alphapn*(Th[i, j] - TL[i, j]), {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, nx}]/(nx*ny*Rpn + RL)

P = Sum[alphapn*(qh[i, j] - qL[i, j]), {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, nx}]

eta = 100*P/Sum[qh[i, j], {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, nx}]

Tf[1, j] = Tfin

Tc[1, j] = Tcin

Tfav[i, j] = (Tf[i, j] + Tf[i + 1, j])/2

Tcav[i, j] = (Tc[i, j] + Tc[i + 1, j])/2
```

Comment: What difficulty are you facing specifically? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarcoB I have no clue from where to start...otherwise I would have posted my try..

Comment: You will need to provide more information on the problem you are trying to solve, at the very least, with some context for the “instructions” you posted. Also translations of the formulae in MMA format would be nice. It still seems unlikely that somebody will take it upon themselves to do your task for you from scratch...

Comment: The biggest problem with your post, I think, is that you do not say what do you want to find (unknowns) and what are the starting values of the iterative process.

Comment: @zhk Could you refer paper or book where you taken this model?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Here is the link to the paper. http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apenergy.2015.03.036

Comment: @yarchik the unknowns are `P` and `eta`.

Answer (score 1):

We can organize computation in 3 steps. First, we calculate transition matrix `tij` for every temperature required as follows

```
Tfav[i, j] = (Tf[i, j] + Tf[i + 1, j])/2;
Tcav[i, j] = (Tc[i, j] + Tc[i + 1, j])/2;

qh1 = cf*mf*(Tf[i, j] - Tf[i + 1, j])/ny;
qh2 = hf*Sf[i, j]*(Tfav[i, j] - Th[i, j]);
qh3 = alphapn*I1*Th[i, j] + Kpn*(Th[i, j] - TL[i, j]) - 0.5*I1^2*Rpn;
qL1 = cc*mc*(Tc[i + 1, j] - Tc[i, j])/ny;
qL2 = hc*Sc[i, j]*(TL[i, j] - Tcav[i, j]);
qL3 = alphapn*I1*TL[i, j] + Kpn*(Th[i, j] - TL[i, j]) + 0.5*I1^2*Rpn;

sol = Solve[{qh1 == qh2, qh2 == qh3, qL1 == qL2, 
    qL2 == qL3}, {Tf[i + 1, j], Tc[i + 1, j], Th[i, j], TL[i, j]}][[1]]

tij = {Tf[i + 1, j], Tc[i + 1, j], Th[i, j], TL[i, j]} /. sol
```

On the second step we use `tij` to compute temperature with `I1=0`. We don't know how surface areas `Sc[i,j], Sf[i,j]` can be defined, but in this code its are given constants

```
alphan = -1.72*10^(-4);
alphap = 2.037*10^(-4);
L = 1.3*10^(-3);
A = 2.08*10^(-6);
kp = 1.265;
kn = 1.011;
sigmap = 1.314 10^-5;
sigman = 1.119 10^-5;
alphapn = alphap - alphan;
Rpn = L/(A)*(sigmap + sigman);
RL = 1;
Kpn = (A/L)*(kp + kn);
cf = 4205;
cc = 4153;
hf = 80;
hc = 1000;
Tfin = 773;
Tcin = 353;
mf = 20;
mc = 200; nx = 20; ny = 10; a = 0.9; b = 0.49;

tf = ConstantArray[Tfin, {nx, ny}];
tc = ConstantArray[Tcin, {nx, ny}]; sf = 
 ConstantArray[a/nx b/ny, {nx, ny}]; sc = sf;

Do[th[i, j] = 
  tij[[3]] /. {i -> i, j -> j, Tc[i, j] -> tc[[i, j]], 
    Tf[i, j] -> tf[[i, j]], Sf[i, j] -> sf[[i, j]], 
    Sc[i, j] -> sc[[i, j]], I1 -> 0}; 
 tL[i, j] = 
  tij[[4]] /. {i -> i, j -> j, Tc[i, j] -> tc[[i, j]], 
    Tf[i, j] -> tf[[i, j]], Sf[i, j] -> sf[[i, j]], 
    Sc[i, j] -> sc[[i, j]], I1 -> 0};, {i, nx}, {j, ny}]

I0 = Sum[alphapn*(th[i, j] - tL[i, j]), {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, 
    ny}]/(nx*ny*Rpn + RL)
```

Here we have out `7.63885`. On the last step we organize iterations up to state where $I$ converges:

```
ii[0] = I0; Do[
 Do[Do[tf[[i + 1, j]] = 
     tij[[1]] /. {i -> i, j -> j, Tc[i, j] -> tc[[i, j]], 
       Tf[i, j] -> tf[[i, j]], Sf[i, j] -> sf[[i, j]], 
       Sc[i, j] -> sc[[i, j]], I1 -> ii[k - 1]}; 
    tc[[i + 1, j]] = 
     tij[[2]] /. {i -> i, j -> j, Tc[i, j] -> tc[[i, j]], 
       Tf[i, j] -> tf[[i, j]], Sf[i, j] -> sf[[i, j]], 
       Sc[i, j] -> sc[[i, j]], I1 -> ii[k - 1]};, {i, 1, 
     nx - 1}];, {j, ny}];
 Do[th[i, j] = 
   tij[[3]] /. {i -> i, j -> j, Tc[i, j] -> tc[[i, j]], 
     Tf[i, j] -> tf[[i, j]], Sf[i, j] -> sf[[i, j]], 
     Sc[i, j] -> sc[[i, j]], I1 -> ii[k - 1]}; 
  tL[i, j] = 
   tij[[4]] /. {i -> i, j -> j, Tc[i, j] -> tc[[i, j]], 
     Tf[i, j] -> tf[[i, j]], Sf[i, j] -> sf[[i, j]], 
     Sc[i, j] -> sc[[i, j]], I1 -> ii[k - 1]};, {i, nx}, {j, ny}];
 ii[k] = Sum[
    alphapn*(th[i, j] - tL[i, j]), {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, 
     ny}]/(nx*ny*Rpn + RL);, {k, 1, 10}]
```

We can plot $I-I0$ on every step to check convergence

```
ListLinePlot[Table[ii[k] - I0, {k, 0, 10}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]
Finally we calculate

```
P = 
  Sum[alphapn*(qh3 - qL3) /. {i -> i, j -> j, Th[i, j] -> th[i, j], 
     TL[i, j] -> tL[i, j], Sf[i, j] -> sf[[i, j]], 
     Sc[i, j] -> sc[[i, j]], I1 -> I0}, {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, ny}];
eta = 100*
   P/Sum[qh3 /. {i -> i, j -> j, Th[i, j] -> th[i, j], 
       TL[i, j] -> tL[i, j], Sf[i, j] -> sf[[i, j]], 
       Sc[i, j] -> sc[[i, j]], I1 -> I0}, {i, 1, nx}, {j, 1, ny}];

{P, eta}

Out[]= {0.0208876, 0.00331435}
```

Comment: First of thank you for your efforts. How to plot `P vs Tfin`, `P vs mf` and `P vs Sf`? This will show whether we are getting the correct results or not?

Comment: @zhk To get result as in the paper we should use same input data. But I didn't  see definition of `Sc[i,j], Sf[i,j]` in the paper and in your code. Also your question is not about `P vs Tfin`, `P vs mf`, or `P vs Sf`, but about code of iterative  process. Could you add this extension to your post with some picture what exactly you asking about?

Comment: I agree with you about the incomplete info from the paper. But by plotting `P vs Tfin`, `P vs mf`, or `P vs Sf` or `eta vs Tfin` or `eta vs mf` will enable us to interpret the results to the best of our understanding.

Comment: @zhk Ok! Have you any version of `Sc, Sf`?

Comment: When can take a fix value for it say `Sc=Sf=0.5`.

Comment: @zhk If `Sf=0.5` then how we can plot `P vs Sf`? Can you think about your problem more realistic?

Comment: I meant to say in other cases such as `P vs Tfin, P vs mf`